# Change or clear focus on QLineEdit when done editing by pressing Enter and only send one signal in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a behavior in which when I finished editing a text, the focus either moves to the next child or clear the focus on the current field when I pressed "Enter". I would then get one signal to trigger a part of the code.

When I do editingFinished() and reimplement keyReleaseEvent() for "Enter" with focusNextChild() or clearFocus(), I get two signals for the text edit, one when the "Enter" is pressed, and one when the focus is change via focusNextChild() or clearFocus().  The extra signal is undesirable.

If I do returnPressed() and reimplement keyReleaseEvent() for "Enter" with focusNextChild() or clearFocus(), it would only create one signal, but I also want the signal to be created when the user exits the lineEdit via tab() or mouse click on any other line items, which would not be the case if I use returnPressed()

Ideally, I could use a signal when a lineEdit loses focus, its connected to a slot that runs the code and I can reimplement the keyReleaseEvent() for "Enter" to set the focus, but it doesn't seem like such a signal exists in Qt.

Does anyone have recommendations on how to implement this or a better way to approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect/disconnect signals when you want. For example, when you focus in the QLineEdit you can connect both listed signals to slot which will disconnect those two connections and move focus to the next child. Thus, you will have only one signal processed.

Another solution - you can call QLineEdit.blockSignals(true) in the beginning of the slot and call QLineEdit.blockSignals(false) in the end of the slot. In this case whatever you do in the slot you will not trigger any signal in QLineEdit and no duplicates will arise.

Comment: QLineEdit.blockSignals() is just what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Alvin C Then close the question as solved - choose this answer.